# How do I cycle through array and multiply every new number with the next?

Tags: php

**This is what I have so far:**

```
<?php
    $ask_number = readline("Gimme a number?");
    $array = Array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ask_number; $i++) {
        $array[$i] = $i;
    }
    return 0;
    var_dump($sum);
?>
```

I can get it to ask for a number and create an array.

**What I want it to do;**

I want it to do this:
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6.. etc.

Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: Do you need to output as `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6` as well? `[$i]` is not need, can just be `[]` PHP auto increments, unless you need the matching key.

Comment: (I'll edit the main post!) Nope, I just need the result.

Comment: Besides that this might be a learning experience, there is an in-built function to calculate the product of an array [array_product](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php#refsect1-function.array-product-description). You could also create your own equivalent as another learning activity using [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php#refsect1-function.array-reduce-description).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for `range()` and `foreach()`

```
<?php
$ask_number = 6;//desired number
$array = range(1,$ask_number);//create array
$multiply = 1; //define multiply variable
foreach( $array as $val ){ 
   $multiply *= $val ;  // multiple value
}
var_dump($multiply ); // print value
//in case you want sum
var_dump(array_sum($array));
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/693sl